# How specific does an API's routing need to be?

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, restful-url

I'm creating an API, I have a user that I can request by calling:

`/api/request/user/{id}`

This works fine.

Say each user had a set of skills, could be one skill or 100.

I want to get all the skills for a specific user.

Would I be super specific and make it so that you'll have to call:

`/api/request/user/{id}/skills`

Or does this:

`/api/request/skills/{id}` (where `{id}` is the user's `id`)

suffice?

Is there a REST API standard I should be following or is it flexible ?

Any advice is highly appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `skills` is user's property, let's consider it as sub-resource. Getting sub-resources is based on nesting URL ([hierarchical way](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/308349/rest-api-handling-subresources)), so `/api/request/user/{id}/skills` would be great!

In `/api/request/skills/{id}` case `id` should be an identifier of skill to make your API intuitive.

Also remember about naming [convention](http://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/). Be consistent, your `skills` resource is plural so let's rename `user` to `users`.

So, to sum up

`/api/request/users/{user_id}`

`/api/request/users/{user_id}/skills`

`/api/request/skills/{skill_id}`

would be nice.